# Adding elements to an ordered list on click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Entering the data in the input field and on clicking the 'Add New' button, element should be added in the list. Here, help me to find out the error

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dataAdd = [];
  $("#addNew").click(function() {
    dataAdd.push($(this).data('#nameList'));
    console.log(data.length);
  });
});
```

```html
<ol id="nameList">
  <li>aston</li>
  <li>baily</li>
  <li>clairne</li>
</ol>
<input type="text" id="data" placeholder="Enter data">
<button id="addNew">Add New</button>
```

Comment: The first obvious error in the snippet is that you haven't added jQuery

Comment: Why you trying to push value into variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
  var dataAdd = [];
  $("#addNew").click(function() {
        $('#nameList').append('<li>'+$('#data').val()+'</li>');
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need smth like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addNew").click(function(){
        $("#nameList").append("<li>" + $("#data").val() + "</li>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what are you doing here...

```
dataAdd.push($(this).data('#nameList'));
```

You can access DOM elements with jQuery just referencing css-selector in brackets, like this `$('css-selector')`

That snippet does the trick:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dataAdd = [];
  $("#addNew").click(function() {
    var value = $('#data').val();
    if(value) {
      dataAdd.push(value);
      $('#nameList').append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
      $('#data').val('');
    }
    console.log(dataAdd.length);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="nameList">
  <li>aston</li>
  <li>baily</li>
  <li>clairne</li>
</ol>
<input type="text" id="data" placeholder="Enter data">
<button id="addNew">Add New</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to append the `li` with the value of input type text not the button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dataAdd = [];
  $("#addNew").click(function() {
    dataAdd.push($('#data').val());
    $('#nameList').append('<li>'+$('#data').val()+'</li>');
    console.log(dataAdd.length);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="nameList">
  <li>aston</li>
  <li>baily</li>
  <li>clairne</li>
</ol>
<input type="text" id="data" placeholder="Enter data">
<button id="addNew">Add New</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dataAdd = [];
  $("#addNew").click(function() {
  var htm='<li>'+$('#data').val()+'</li>';
  $("#nameList").append(htm);
  $('#data').val('');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="nameList">
  <li>aston</li>
  <li>baily</li>
  <li>clairne</li>
</ol>
<input type="text" id="data" placeholder="Enter data">
<button id="addNew">Add New</button>
```